# Initialize an array to a value

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to populate/instantiate a C# array with a single value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014005/how-to-populate-instantiate-a-c-sharp-array-with-a-single-value)

Given double array

```
   double[] constraintValue = new double[UnUsedServices.Count];
```

I want to initialize all entry with `-1`, is there a simple syntax to do it?

Comment: On the same line with out for-loops?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014005/how-to-populate-instantiate-a-c-sharp-array-with-a-single-value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for(int i = 0; i < constraintValue.Length; i++)
    constraintValue[i] = -1;
```

Comment: `Count` is for collections. Replace by `Length` for arrays

Comment: I used the length value from the question

Comment: Hmm, this seems to be the intuitive one...i just expect c# might have some syntatic sugar, but it doesn't seems to be.

Answer (score 5):

```
double[] constraintValue = Enumerable.Repeat<double>(-1d,UnUsedServices.Count).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 double[] constraintValue = Enumerable.Repeat(-1D, UnUsedServices.Count).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

The exact answer to your question is :

```
for(var i =0; i < constraintValue.Length; i ++)
{
    constraintValue[i] = -1;
}
```

However, if you want to have "unset" values, why don't you use `Nullable<double>` ?

```
double?[] constraintValue = new double?[UnUsedServices.Count];

constraintValue[10] = 42D;
constraintValue[20] = 0D;

var x1 = contraintValue[10].HasValue; // true
var x1val = contraintValue[10].Value; // 42D

var x2 = contraintValue[20].HasValue; // true
var x2val = contraintValue[20].Value; // 0D

var x3 = contraintValue[10].HasValue; // false
//var x3val = contraintValue[10].Value; // exception
```

Comment: Thanks, learnt new thing here.

Answer (score 1):

you can try with

```
for(int i =0; i < constraintValue.Length; i ++)
{
constraintValue[i] = -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you would call this "easy":

```
double[] constraintValue = new double[]{ -1, -1, 
                                         ... (UnUsedServices.Count times)};
```

And of course, the standard way to do this is to *loop* over each array item to initialize it:

```
for(int i = 0; i < constraintValue.Length; i++)
{
    constraintValue[i] = -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < constraintValue.Length; i++)
    constraintValue[i] = -1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    int[] initilize_array = newint[10];

    for (int i = 0; i <initilize_array.Length; i++)

    {

    initilize_array[i] = -1;

    }
```

It's the easiest way

Answer (score 0):

If you need performance faster then Enumerable.Repeat do it in parallel using the TPL:

```
double[] constraintValue = new double[UnUsedServices.Count];
Parallel.For(0, UnUsedServices.Count, index => constraintValue[index] = -1);
```

Comment: No. Not here. Benchmark it, you will see a large performance degradation. Why? because the parallelized job is so small and cheap. If you add parrallelism, your application will have to workf with threads, context switch, locks, etc. This structural cost is quite larger than the benefits.

Comment: And to add to steve's comments, you're also destroying memory localization.  Accessing sequential memory locations is much quicker than "random" access to memory, which would be the result of parallelizing it.

Comment: Yeah, ignore this. I underestimated how much this scenario is optimized. I benched it against Enumerable.Repeat. Enumerable.Repeat is horribly slow, but the simple for loop in the accepted answer is much faster then both solutions until about 10million entries in the array at which point the Parallel is equally fast as the for loop.