# C# string[] arrayA return null value in arrayA[3]

Tags: c#

I have many array in my code, example;

```
string[] arrayA = new string[31];
```

and i need to put the value from the arrays into SQL Database

```
SqlCommand commA = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO dbo.DatabaseA" +
            " (ColumnA) VALUES" +
            " (@ColumnA)", connA);
commA.Parameters.Add("@ColumnA", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = arrayA[3];
```

Why does the `@ColumnA` return error 'the value is not supplied' or to be precise `arrayA[3] = null`? I always thought unassigned string[] have `""` as initial value.

**If initially i assigned `arrayA[3] = ""` before the `SQLCommand` the code work just fine.**

Is there a way to populate the all `string[] arrayA`with `""` without using for loop?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to populate/instantiate a C# array with a single value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014005/how-to-populate-instantiate-a-c-sharp-array-with-a-single-value)

Comment: Declare your array differently. string[] arrayA = Enumerable.Range(0, 31)
                            .Select(i => string.Empty)
                            .ToArray();

Comment: The initial value of every item in the array will always be the default value for the array item type.  In the case of reference types, including strings, this will always be null.  And don't be scared to use loops where needed, they don't bite.

Comment: @Hakunamatata I read that Enumerable is slower than loop

Comment: For your case generating 31 elements using  Enumerable will not make any noticeable performance difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the code supplied there is no value assigned to `arrayA[3]` the array is simply a container for values and sets each value to the default value for the type similar to going `default(string)`.

Now as `string` is a **reference type** the default value for the string is `null` however a **value type** `int` for example will have a default value of `0`.

We can easily test this such as.

```
string[] arrayA = new string[31];
var s = arrayA[3]; //is null as string is a reference type

int[] arrayB = new int[31];
var i = arrayB[3]; //equals 0 as default(int) = 0
```

Now as pointed in comments there are easy ways to populate an array and the referenced comment points to [How to populate/instantiate a C# array with a single value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014005/how-to-populate-instantiate-a-c-sharp-array-with-a-single-value)

**The snippet below is from the answer above**

```
public static void Populate<T>(this T[] arr, T value ) {
  for ( int i = 0; i < arr.Length;i++ ) {
    arr[i] = value;
  }
}
```

This can be called by:

```
arrayA.Populate("");
```

So in the call:

```
commA.Parameters.Add("@ColumnA", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = arrayA[3];
```

In fact `arrayA[3] = null`

**EDIT** 
The snippet above is an extension method (as seen by the `this` keyword on the first parameter in the method signature). This must be in a `static class` similar to below.

```
public static class ArrayExtensions
{
    public static void Populate<T>(this T[] arr, T value)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            arr[i] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

As for the question

> Is there a way to populate the all string[] arrayAwith "" without
>   using for loop?

All the methods to set the default value of all items in an array will require a loop of some sort and the loop may be a `foreach` or `for` under the hood somewhere.

You could also create a method that would create an array for you of a specified size with a default value.

```
public static T[] CreateArray<T>(int capacity, T defaultValue)
{
    var array = new T[capacity];
    array.Populate(defaultValue);
    return array;
}
```

Which could then be called as:

```
var arrayC = ArrayExtensions.CreateArray<string>(31, "");
s = arrayC[3]; //equals ""
```

However that starts to look too lazy to me.

Comment: where should i put the snippet?

Comment: The snippit is an extension method (as seen by the `this`) in the first parameter. I will update the answer with an example.

Comment: Thanks  for the detailed answer as i I still learning c# and asp.net on my own.

Answer (score 0):

You are not assigned any values to the array . If you need " " ,if there is no value use conditional operators .

```
arrayA[3]==null?"":arrayA[3];
```

[conditional operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4213hs1.aspx)