# Enumerable.Repeat for reference type objects initialization

Tags: c#, reference-type

I have a question about Enumerable.Repeat function.

If I will have a class:

```
class A
{
//code
}
```

And I will create an array, of that type objects:

```
A [] arr = new A[50];
```

And next, I will want to initialize those objects, calling Enumerable.Repeat:

```
arr = Enumerable.Repeat(new A(), 50);
```

Will those objects have the same address in memory?
If I will want to check their hash code, for example in that way:

```
bool theSameHashCode = questions[0].GetHashCode() == questions[1].GetHashCode();
```

This will return me true, and if I will change one object properties, all other objects will change it too.

So my question is: is that properly way, to initialize reference type objects? If not, then what is a better way?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Using `Enumerable.Repeat` this way will initialize only one object and return that object every time when you iterate over the result.

> Will those objects have the same address in memory?

There is only one object.

To achieve what you want, you can do this:

```
Enumerable.Range(1, 50).Select(i => new A()).ToArray();
```

This will return an array of 50 distinct objects of type `A`.

By the way, the fact that `GetHashCode()` returns the same value does not imply that the objects are referentially equal (or simply equal, for that matter). Two non-equal objects can have the same hash code.

Comment: That's weird. I use Enumerable.Repeat to copy an object some dozens of times (so I don't have to copy the values manually) and then edit the properties I'm interested in, and it works flawlessly. So, not really sure what you mean by "one object"

Comment: From MSDN: "Generates a sequence that contains one repeated value." - Maybe you were using value types. In that case you would get a copy every single time.

Comment: No, they are EF entities with both POCO and nested classes

Comment: Hmm... I have just tested this and works as I assumed: `var x = Enumerable.Repeat(new C(), 2); Console.WriteLine(x[0] == x[1]);` prints `true`

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,89605215aab7080f Kapol is correct - it will return the same element n times.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto - I've put an answer to show that only one instance is created: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44937849/259769

Answer (score 7):

Just to help clarify for Camilo, here's some test code that shows the issue at hand:

```
void Main()
{
    var foos = Enumerable.Repeat(new Foo(), 2).ToArray();
    foos[0].Name = "Jack";
    foos[1].Name = "Jill";
    Console.WriteLine(foos[0].Name);    
}

public class Foo
{
    public string Name;
}
```

This prints "Jill". Thus it shows that `Enumerable.Repeat` is only creating one instance of the `Foo` class.

Comment: Thanks for the test. I'll have to revisit the code that does this, I'm probably forgetting about something

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto - No worries. I just thought that this was worth clarifying.

Answer (score 3):

When using the following code to create an array:

```
var foos = Enumerable.Repeat(new Foo(), 2).ToArray();
```

The reason why each location in the array is the same is because you are passing an object, and not a function that creates an object, the code above is the same as:

```
var foo = new Foo();
var foos = Enumerable.Repeat(foo , 2).ToArray();
```

The reason above also explains why using a Select statement, like in the code below, creates a new object for each entry, because you are passing a function that dictates how each object is created, rather than the object itself.

```
Enumerable.Range(1, 2).Select(i => new Foo()).ToArray();
```

I would use a simple for loop to populate an array with new reference types.