# Generate one number and fill array

Tags: c#

I need to generate only one number and fill this number in array with 15 elements.

My code:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] array = new int[15];
            Console.WriteLine("Generate array: ");
            Generator(array);
            Console.WriteLine();
            GeneratorConst(array);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static void Generator(int[] array)
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
            {
                array[i] = rnd.Next(1, 30);
                Console.Write(array[i] + ", ");
            }
        }

        static void GeneratorConst(int[] array)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.Write(array[i] + ", ");
            }
        }
```

Now I generate 15 various numbers. How can I fix it to get only one the same number in each position in 15-elements array?

Comment: Get `rnd.Next(1, 30);` out side of the loop ? `array[i] = rnd.Next(1, 30);` read as  put a new random at index I. Imo it's simple logical mistake. this one was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers.

Comment: `Enumerable.Repeat` may be worth a squiz.

Comment: `var results = Enumerable.Repeat(rnd.Next(1, 30), 15).ToArray();`

Comment: And if we are talking about array initialisation I will recommend [How to populate/instantiate a C# array with a single value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014005).

Comment: But between typo and dupe of this one I will go for typo.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014005/how-to-populate-instantiate-a-c-sharp-array-with-a-single-value I think this one will be helpful for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

modify your code like so:

```
 static void Generator(int[] array)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        var num = rnd.Next(1, 30);
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            array[i] = num;
        }
    }
```

rnd.Next is the line where the number generation is, which means each time you call it you get a new number.
by taking it out of the loop you generate a single number and then assign the number to the array every iteration

Comment: You should *really* move the random object out  of the method into a static field

Comment: why would i do such a thing? the only case this might be useful is if the developer would like the same number even on different time he calls the generator method. and even in that case i would recommend encapsulating it in a generator object instead of moving it to a static field, because IMHO static fields are just straight out a bad thing

Answer (score 1):

I personally like this way because it's a bit cleaner:

```
public static int[] Generator()
{
    var randNum = new Random().Next(1, 30);
    arr = Enumerable.Repeat(randNum, arr.Length).ToArray();
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: Unless you pass `arr` as `ref` this will have no effect outside of this function?

Comment: Yes, your absolutely right. I just  wrapped the code in the mentioned method without giving it any thought. I will edit my suggestion right away.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
static void GeneratorConst(int[] array)
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    var val = rnd.Next(1, 30);
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        array[i] = val;
        Console.Write(array[i] + ", ");
    }
}
```