# Powershell to C# syntax conversion

Tags: c#, powershell

Can anybody help to convert this Powershell line of code to C#, please?

```
$query.TextFileColumnDataTypes = ,2 * $worksheet.Cells.Columns.Count
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This expression:

```
,2 * $count
```

Creates an `[int[]]` (an array of `[int]`'s) of length `$count` where each item has the value initialized to `2`.

In C# you could either create the same array [with `Enumerable.Repeat()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014005/how-to-populate-instantiate-a-c-sharp-array-with-a-single-value):

```
query.TextFileColumnDataTypes = Enumerable.Repeat(2, worksheet.Cells.Columns.Count).ToArray()
```

Or initialize each item manually:

```
var array = new int[worksheet.Cells.Columns.Count];
for(int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    array[i] = 2;
query.TextFileColumnDataTypes = array;
```

Answer (score 2):

To complement [Mathias R. Jessen's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69495841/45375):

- **.NET Core 2.0+ / .NET 5+ / .NET Standard 2.1+** - but *not* .NET Framework - now offer a convenient static **[`Array.Fill()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.array.fill)** method:

  ```
  var a = new int[3];
  // Note: There is also an overload to target a *subrange*.
  Array.Fill(a, 42);  // -> int[3] { 42, 42, 42 }
  ```
- [`Enumerable.Repeat()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Linq.Enumerable.Repeat) is convenient, but *slow* compared to the `for` solution.
- To take the drudgery out of the `for` solution, you can define an *extension method*, adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1014015/45375).

  ```
  public static T[] Fill<T>(this T[] a, T value ) {
    for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; ++i) { a[i] = value; }
    return a;
  }

  // Sample call:
  var a = new int[3].Fill(42);  // -> int[3] { 42, 42, 42 }
  ```